# authentication with rails 4 error

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, controller

I get error `undefined method 'authenticate' for nil:NilClass...` after in login page submit the username and passwords. I am new in rails and following some tutorials.

in my `access_controller.rb`

```
class AccessController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def create    
        if params[:username].present? && params[:password].present?
            found_user = AdminUser.where(:username => params[:username]).first
            if found_user
                authorized_user = found_user.authenticate(params[:password])
            end
        end
        if authorized_user
            # TODO: mark user as logged in
            flash[:notice] = "You are now logged in."
            redirect_to(:action => 'index')
        else
            flash[:notice] = "Invalid username/password combination."
            redirect_to(:action => 'login')
        end
    end
```

in my login page: `login.html.erb`

```
<% @page_title = "Admin Login" %>
<div class="login">
    <%= form_tag access_create_path do  %>  
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><%= label_tag :username  %></td>
            <td><%= text_field_tag :username %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%= label_tag :password %></td>
            <td><%= password_field_tag :password %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><%= submit_tag("Log In") %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `found_user` is `nil`.Try `inspecting` the `found_user` and make sure it is not `nil`.

Comment: show me your authenticate method.

Comment: @RubyOnRails I don't have authenticate method! how should I define it?

Comment: Yes you have to define it! Are you using devise for authentication.